# Can't get values for a table located inside a frame through Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Below is the error I get when I try to apply the 'table[0].$$eval' method (see code snipped below) :

```
Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '# 297d0e3 > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)' is not a valid selector
```

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')


const scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false,defaultViewport: null,args: [
        '--disable-web-security',
        '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process'
      ]});

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://dealers.carwow.co.uk/dealers/sign_in')

    await page.type('#dealer_email', 'email')
    await page.type('#dealer_password', 'password')
    await page.click('#new_dealer > p > input')
    
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    let xpathArray = await page.$x('//*[@id="dealer-dashboard"]/div[3]/div/div/a')
    await xpathArray[0].click() 
    
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    const frameHandle = await page.$x('//*[@id="klipfolio-iframe"]');

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));


    const frame = await frameHandle[0].contentFrame();

    await frame.waitForXPath('//*[@id="0297d0e3"]/table');
    
    const table = await frame.$x('//*[@id="0297d0e3"]/table');

  console.log(table)

    

    browser.close()
};
```

The above function returns an array containing a ElementHandle (below) rather than an element.

```
[
  ElementHandle {
    _disposed: false,
    _context: ExecutionContext {
      _client: [CDPSession],
      _world: [DOMWorld],
      _contextId: 17,
      _contextName: ''
    },
    _client: CDPSession {
      eventsMap: [Map],
      emitter: [Object],
      _callbacks: Map(0) {},
      _connection: [Connection],
      _targetType: 'page',
      _sessionId: '326BCCF50B6BBE8CA175CB21AB46C382'
    },
    _remoteObject: {
      type: 'object',
      subtype: 'node',
      className: 'HTMLTableElement',
      description: 'table.layout-grid',
      objectId: '3652992625290954585.17.4'
    },
    _page: Page {
      eventsMap: Map(0) {},
      emitter: [Object],
      _closed: false,
      _timeoutSettings: [TimeoutSettings],
      _pageBindings: Map(0) {},
      _javascriptEnabled: true,
      _workers: Map(0) {},
      _fileChooserInterceptors: Set(0) {},
      _userDragInterceptionEnabled: false,
      _client: [CDPSession],
      _target: [Target],
      _keyboard: [Keyboard],
      _mouse: [Mouse],
      _touchscreen: [Touchscreen],
      _accessibility: [Accessibility],
      _frameManager: [FrameManager],
      _emulationManager: [EmulationManager],
      _tracing: [Tracing],
      _coverage: [Coverage],
      _screenshotTaskQueue: [ScreenshotTaskQueue],
      _viewport: null
    },
    _frameManager: FrameManager {
      eventsMap: [Map],
      emitter: [Object],
      _frames: [Map],
      _contextIdToContext: [Map],
      _isolatedWorlds: [Set],
      _client: [CDPSession],
      _page: [Page],
      _networkManager: [NetworkManager],
      _timeoutSettings: [TimeoutSettings],
      _mainFrame: [Frame]
    }
  }
]
```

I have tried iterating over the array then doing applying the method (see below) to extract data from a table (see picture)

What exactly is an Element handle and how do I solve  this issue?

```
table[0].$$eval('#\30 297d0e3 > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)', rows => {
        return Array.from(rows, row => {
         const columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');
         return Array.from(columns, column => column.innerText);
        });
      });
```

[image: Element Tree]

Answer (score 1):

If you need a selector with a number in its id, try this workaround:

```js
table[0].$$eval('[id="the_number"] > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)', rows => {
```